# Figuring out my grades lol

Tags: word-problem

I have 6 HW assignments If my assignments are worth 25% of my grade and each assignment is worth 50 pts. And out of that 25 percent what would that 25 percent change too if I got a zero on one of the 6 assignments.

Comment: Would it change to 20 percent?

Comment: $x:(6\cdot 50)=100:25$ where $x$ is the total number of points for the grade then find $x$ and the result is $x:(5\cdot 50)$ where $a:b=\frac ab$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each homework assignment is worth the same number of points, each one is worth $\frac{1}{6}\times 25\% = 4.166...\%$ of your grade. So if you remove one of the six assignments, the rest make up $\frac{5}{6}\times 25\% = 20.833...\%$ of your grade.